# I receive error 1 message when trying to run makepkg -sic for yay

Tags: arch

I cloned yay through `git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git`. I Enter the directory and run `makepkg -sic` but I unfortunately get the error:

```
==> Making package: yay 10.1.0-1 (Mon 26 Oct 2020 06:25:36 AM +0330)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Downloading yay-10.1.0.tar.gz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   118  100   118    0     0     97      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    97
100  339k  100  339k    0     0   103k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  168k
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    yay-10.1.0.tar.gz ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting yay-10.1.0.tar.gz with bsdtar
==> Starting build()...
go build -v -trimpath -mod=readonly -modcacherw -ldflags '-s -w -extldflags "-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now" -X "main.yayVersion=10.1.0" -X "main.localePath=/usr/share/locale/"' -buildmode=pie -o yay
go: github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2@v2.0.1: Get "https://gocenter.io/github.com/%21jguer/go-alpm/v2/@v/v2.0.1.mod": dial tcp 35.230.74.213:443: i/o timeout
make: *** [Makefile:127: yay] Error 1
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the error consistently? If so, it looks like the host you are using to build does not have access to GoCenter.

Comment: I actually did. Finally I had to give up and use one of the previously compiled instances.

Comment: i would also try doing a `go get github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2` from the host to see how it is behaving. When i did it locally, i found that the `/v2` directory wasn't existing in the source of the go module and it always defaults to `github.com/jguer/go-alpm`

Comment: I ran `go get github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2` and this is the output:

`cannot find package "github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2 (from $GOROOT)
        /home/nino/go/src/github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2 (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: Make sure you are in module mode by doing `go mod init` first and then run `go get github.com/Jguer/go-alpm/v2` . I see GoCenter was able to serve it (no timeouts) but there is a build error because of another dependency. May be the module author should be notified about this.
`fatal error: 'alpm.h' file not found
 #include <alpm.h>`

Comment: I'm actually pretty much unfamiliar with the concepts you mentioned. I checked again and, to my surprise, the installation file had been actually created despite the error and I managed to install yay with it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

#### exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH

check prerequisites. see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ar … Repository

But most of the time there is a problem with gcc, which can be solved in the following way :

1. pamac install base-devel
2. choose a gcc number from list